# How to make a vertical bar that follows its user in a specific area?

Tags: html, css

I do have a simple box designed in HTML and CSS. If you want to see it, just [use this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zk755cr9/3/).

Now I want to design a bar at the right side of the box, overlaying ~10-20px of the right side/image.

It should be a bit transparent, slighty different-colored and so on. Nothing hard.

But I also wish that this bar has a little image or text (e.g. "floating text", 90° flipped), that follows the user when he scrolls up and down. BUT not further than the maximum top or bottom line of the box.

**How can I design a bar that follows the user in a specific area?**

Do clearify it, I just used my ultimate paint skills to paint what I'm looking for:

[image]

The orange area would be the area where my box may float. No more than this, not less than this. The red thingy should be the box.

---

As jsfiddle.net can only be linked with providing code, I'll do this:

HTML:

```
<section class="mbox">
     <h2>Business PC</h2>

    <div class="mbox_content">
         <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr!
            <span>sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam</span>
        </h3>

        <p>Erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <img src="http://www.club-3d.com/tl_files/club3d/uploads/en/content/Accesories/CAC-1052/cac-1052_use_01.png" alt="Testbild">
</section>
```

CSS:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);
 body, html {
    height:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    background:#5cafff;
    font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
.mbox {
    z-index: 1;
    margin: 2em;
    position:relative;
    background: #ff1a00;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #ffffff 33%, #ff1a00 100%);
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    height:600px;
    clear:both;
}
.mbox * {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
.mbox_content {
    z-index: 2;
    float:left;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #ffffff;
    width:60%;
    height:560px;
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
.mbox img {
    z-index:-1;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    max-height:200px;
}
.mbox hr {
    z-index: 2;
    float:left;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    margin-top: 30px;
    border-width: 15px 0 15px 20px;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #ffffff;
}
.mbox h2 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size:1em;
    top:-0.7em;
    left: 0.5em;
    position:absolute;
    color:#fff;
    background:#ff1a00;
    padding:0 1em;
    border:1px solid #fff;
    border-radius:1em;
}
.mbox_content h3 {
    font-size:1.4em;
    color:#666;
    border-left:2px solid #ccc;
    padding-left: 1em;
    margin-bottom:0.5em;
}
.mbox_content h3 span {
    margin-top:0.5em;
    display:block;
    font-size:0.7em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight:normal;
}
```

Comment: So in your fiddle, you want the GPU image and > to scroll with the page but stop at the top or the bottom of its container?

Comment: Nono, not the image. A new bar/div, that displays "close" or an image for that. So when you open the news, it would be in the top-right corner. As you scroll through the wall of text, it scrolls with you until it's in the lower-right corner, but it won't go further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/zk755cr9/40/)**

I tryed to do as mutch as possible in css and html but the scrolling part does need some javascript.

The only thing i did not do is make the bar stop at the end of the container. This would recquire even more javascript.

So what i did was make a extra div. positioned it `position:absolute` and `right:0` so it would allways be on  the outer most right of the container.
Added a `overflow:hidden` so our close button would not go over its container.

Added a container `<div class="rotate">` for the rotating of the text.
added the text close.

Added some javascript that addes the current scroll amout to the close button.

```js
var i = document.querySelector(".stickbar .close");
var doc = document.documentElement;
window.onscroll = function () {
    var top = (window.pageYOffset || doc.scrollTop) - (doc.clientTop || 0);
    i.style.right = (20 + top) + "px";

}
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);
 body, html {
    height: 500vh;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    background:#5cafff;
    font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
.mbox {
    z-index: 1;
    margin: 2em;
    position:relative;
    background: #ff1a00;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #ffffff 33%, #ff1a00 100%);
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    height:600px;
    clear:both;
}
.mbox * {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
.mbox_content {
    z-index: 2;
    float:left;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #ffffff;
    width:60%;
    height:560px;
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
.mbox img {
    z-index:-1;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    max-height:200px;
}
.mbox hr {
    z-index: 2;
    float:left;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    margin-top: 30px;
    border-width: 15px 0 15px 20px;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #ffffff;
}
.mbox h2 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size:1em;
    top:-0.7em;
    left: 0.5em;
    position:absolute;
    color:#fff;
    background:#ff1a00;
    padding:0 1em;
    border:1px solid #fff;
    border-radius:1em;
}
.mbox_content h3 {
    font-size:1.4em;
    color:#666;
    border-left:2px solid #ccc;
    padding-left: 1em;
    margin-bottom:0.5em;
}
.mbox_content h3 span {
    margin-top:0.5em;
    display:block;
    font-size:0.7em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight:normal;
}
.stickbar {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 600px;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    background-color: Orange;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.stickbar .rotate {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -o-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
.stickbar .close {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 50px;
    right: 20px;
    bottom: -0.7em;
    background-color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<section class="mbox">
     <h2>Business PC</h2>

    <div class="mbox_content">
         <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr!
            <span>sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam</span>
        </h3>

        <p>Erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    </div>
    <hr/>
    <img src="http://www.club-3d.com/tl_files/club3d/uploads/en/content/Accesories/CAC-1052/cac-1052_use_01.png" alt="Testbild" />
    <div class="stickbar">
        <div class="rotate"> <span class="close">Close</span>

        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Oh this is pretty rad! I guess I can take the "stop at bottom line" part. But this really is what I've been looking for. Thanks for your effort, helped me a lot! So now, let's crawl through the code...

Comment: @Trollwut i wish you good luck understanding the code and if you want i can explain some of the javascript later today. (i'll just edit the answer)

Comment: Oh, the JS won't be the problem. But I haven't done CSS since 1860. :D Thanks for your offer!

Comment: Oh, I've seen that "right answer" doesn't mean "get bounty". FIxed that.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

```
<div class="a-box"></div>

.a-box {
    width:180px;
    height:200px;
    position:fixed;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    right:60px;
    top:40%;
    padding: 20px;    
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/d68mzmeu/)

Comment: Oh sorry my friend, this is not what I'm looking for. I edited the question with my ultimate paint skills to clearify it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best solution for you:

[JSFIDDLE #1](https://jsfiddle.net/8oj0sge4/5/)

```js
var fixed = document.getElementById('fixed-div');
var fixedHeight = fixed.parentNode.scrollHeight - fixed.offsetHeight;

fixed.parentNode.parentNode.onscroll = function() {
  fixed.style.top = Math.min(this.scrollTop, fixedHeight) + "px";
}
```

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1500px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding-top: 380px;
}
#wrapper .scrollbar-container {
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
#wrapper .scrollable {
  height: 1500px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  position: relative;
}
#wrapper .fixed {
  right: 10px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 500px;
  background: black;
  overflow: none;
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="scrollbar-container">
    <div class="scrollable">
      <div id="fixed-div" class="fixed">
        close (fixed)
      </div>
      Text inside Div that moves with scroll.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

or you could also try something like this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ZLbqn/219/).

```css
.outer {
  width: 200px;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: gray;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.inner {
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  position: fixed;
  margin-left: 150px
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">close
  </div>
</div>
```